# how to export chart in an excel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to display data fetched from database as a bar chart and then export the data along with chart image into an excel.I could display the bar chart successfully but I am unable to export the data along with the chart to an excel.

Is there any way to export the data and chart into an excel on click of a button?

Here is my javascript code

```
var fetcheddata = '';
var proddata = '';
$( document ).ready(function (){
    $('#chart-container-1').hide();
     $('#chart-container').show();
     $.ajax({
        url:"index.php?r=jobready/get-data",
        method: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
                fetcheddata = data;
                console.log(data);
                var data_e = JSON.parse(fetcheddata);
                console.log(data_e);
                var rating = [];
                var variety = [];
                var quality = [];

                for (var i in data_e) {
                    rating.push(data_e[i].ratingid);
                    variety.push(data_e[i].variety);
                    quality.push(data_e[i].quality);
            }
            console.log("Rating:" +rating);
            console.log("Variety:" +variety);
            console.log("Quality:" +quality);

           var chartdata = {
                labels: rating,
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Variety',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: variety
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Quality',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: quality
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata,
                options: {
                    barValueSpacing: 20,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Variety',
                        fontSize: 20
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Product Id'
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Amount'
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]

                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('download-pdf').addEventListener("click", downloadPDF);   
    $("#download-xls").click(function (e) {

});
    $('#product_sales').on("click",function(){
        $('#chart-container-1').show();
        $('#chart-container').hide();
        $.ajax({
        url:"index.php?r=jobready/get-product-data",
        method: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
                proddata = data;
                console.log(data);
                var data_e = JSON.parse(proddata);
                console.log(data_e);
                var flavour = [];
                var munch = [];
                var perk = [];
                var snickers = [];

                for (var i in data_e) {
                    flavour.push(data_e[i].flavour);
                    munch.push(data_e[i].munch);
                    perk.push(data_e[i].perk);
                    snickers.push(data_e[i].snickers);
            }
            console.log("flavour:" +flavour);
            console.log("munch:" +munch);
            console.log("perk:" +perk);
            console.log("snickers:" +snickers);

           var chartdata = {
                labels: flavour,
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Munch',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: munch
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Perk',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: perk
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Snickers',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: snickers
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas_1");

            var barGraph1 = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata,
                options: {
                    barValueSpacing: 20,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Products',
                        fontSize: 20
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Flavour'
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Sales'
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                max: 700,
                                min: 0
                            }
                        }]

                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    });
});
function downloadPDF() {
        var canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas');
    //creates image
    var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

    //creates PDF from img
    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
    doc.setFontSize(20);
    doc.text(15, 15, "Cool Chart");
    doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 280, 150 );
    doc.save('canvas.pdf');
}
```

I am stucked at on click of download-xls jquery function .

Comment: please show code

Comment: Share your code and what is not working for you :)

Comment: Because your tags say php and you didn't show any code, you may also want to check out https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet. It is a library for creating and reading excel files with php. So if you want to create the file server-side you can use this.

Comment: I have updated the code I am trying

Comment: how is php involved in the question? are you lookig for a javascript approach to the problem or php? where is the php code you have tried so far?

Comment: xls file that you want users to download, how do you plan to get or create? Do you want to create the file in frontend using the data returned from ajax? Or do you get a link to the file from your server?

Comment: @NafizAhmed I want to create in front end using data returned from ajax

Comment: I am afraid that it is not a healthy practice. Creating files at client side can create major security issues. And also, I am sorry I am not aware of anything that can serve your purpose.

Comment: @NafizAhmed My requirement is I need to fetch data from db and display that as bar chart. After displaying I need to provide a button on click of which , the chart should be exported as an excel along with chart data and image in the excel.I am able to display it as a bar chart but stucked at exporting as an excel.

Answer (score 0):

So, out of curiosity, I just looked whether you can actually create an excel file in frontend from plain data, and to my surprise, this is what I got.

There is an article on code project that does this. I have posted the link as follows - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1197349/Excel-Files-in-JavaScript-the-Simple-Way. You can look into there for more details.

Hope this helps you. But I still urge you to think about generating the file at the backend.

Comment: not surprising, because excel in xlsx format is just an xml

Comment: Then, my bad. I did not know.